# MiniProfiler erro asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando usar o [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/)

Fiz a seguinte configuração:

```
PM> Install-Package MiniProfiler
```

`PM> Install-Package MiniProfiler.MVC4` (Segundo a Doc atende também o MVC5)

```
PM> Install-Package MiniProfiler.EF6
```

Após isso, em minha View Layout, coloquei o seguinte render

`@StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()` //aqui que se rendeniza o arquivo JS

No meu `Global.asax` a seguinte configuração:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start();
    } 
}

protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    MiniProfiler.Stop();
}
```

e no `Application_Start` os seguintes códigos:

```
  ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ProfilingViewEngine(new RazorViewEngine()));

  MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
```

E por último registrei um Filtro no FilterConfig

```
  filters.Add(new ProfilingActionFilter());
```

Mas qunado fui colocar no meu projeto principal, me aparece o seguinte erro na página, que é o carregamento do JS que se encontra na `MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()` conforme mostrado acima nas configurações.

Bom, ele não carrega o script por completo, ocasionando esse erro, não sei o motivo, ele carrega o JS só pela metade.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

No meu Web.Config, dentro do system.webServer>handlers também coloquei o seguinte:

```
   <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Comment: Como está o arquivo JS? Quais foram as demais modificações que você fez no projeto para funcionar?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, editei minha pergunta, agora está completa com o passo a passo que eu fiz, em uma outra app de teste que eu tinha feito, funcionou tudo certo isso